# Classifying months in periods

Tags: sql, postgresql, row-number

Suppose I have 2 years of data. From January 2010 to Dec 2011.
I want to classify each of the months as periods. So January 2010 will be my 1, February 2010 my 2, and so on until December 2011 my 24 period.

I know I could do it something like:

```
select 
    year,mn, 
    case when year=2010 and mn=01 then 1
    else when year=2010 and mn=02 then 2
    else when year=2010 and mn=03 then 3
    //and so on until // else when year=2011 and mn=12 then 24 end 
from mytable;
```

The result would be something like:

```
year    mn  period
2010    1   1
2010    2   2
2010    3   3
2010    4   4
2010    5   5
2010    6   6
2010    7   7
2010    8   8
2010    9   9
2010    10  10
2010    11  11
2010    12  12
2011    1   13
2011    2   14
2011    3   15
2011    4   16
2011    5   17
2011    6   18
2011    7   19
2011    8   20
2011    9   21
2011    10  22
2011    11  23
2011    12  24
```

I want to avoid this kind of long and not wise method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
    year, mn,
    row_number() over (order by year, mn) as period
from t
```

Answer (score 1):

A cheap version for this particular case:

```
SELECT year, mn, (year - 2010) * 12 + mn AS period
FROM   tbl;
```

This would also account for months that may be missing in your data.
And it would give you consistent numbers even when only selecting *some* rows.

Answer (score 1):

No need for fancy windowing functions. Just do it the simple way. For a given `{epoch-year}` and `{epoch-month}` (e.g., 2010 and 1 respectively), the formula

```
( ( 12*year + mn ) - ( 12*{epoch-year} + {epoch-month} )
```

will give you the offset in month from the epoch. Add 1 to that and you have your period number. That leads you to something like this:

```
select year ,
       mn   ,
       (   ( 12*year         + mn            )
         - ( 12*{epoch-year} + {epoch-month} )
       ) + 1 as period
       ...
from some-table
where   year > {epoch-year}
   OR ( year = {epoch-year} and mn >= {epoch-month} )
```

IF you don't have a specific epoch in mind, you can do something like this:

```
select t.year ,
       t.mn   ,
       (   ( 12*year       + mn          )
         - ( 12*epoch.year + epoch.month )
       ) + 1 as period
       ...

from       ( select year,mn
             from some-table
             order by year , mn
             limit 1
           ) epoch
cross join some-table t
```

You should note that one can come up with a formula to number periods based on period lengths longer than 1 month: just compute the offset in months and and use integer division to divide that offset by the period length in months, thus getting to the sequential period number, something like

```
       (   ( 12*year + mn )
         - ( 12*2010 + 1  )
       ) DIV 3 + 1 as period
```

should give you periods of 3 months in length